# How to animate change between widgets that are depending on condition?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to animation to switch between two widgets after setState call, depending on scrollPosition and I don't know how to do this.

Here is my scroll listener where setState is called

```
@override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      scrollController.addListener(() {
        print('scrolling');
        print(scrollController.position.pixels);
        if(scrollController.position.pixels == 0) {
          setState(() {
            carouselSliderVisible = true;
          });
        }
        else {
          setState(() {
            carouselSliderVisible = false;
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

and here are widgets which I want to animate change from one to another

```
Column(
    children: [
       carouselSliderVisible 
           ? CarouselSlider(
                items: [
                     Text('blablabla'),
                     Text('blabla')
                ],
                options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: size.height * 0.2,
                      enableInfiniteScroll: false
                ),
           )
           : Text('Polecane'),
```

These widgets has different height and it's important also for me that change of height will animate too.

Comment: It would be easier if you could tell how you like to animate, also a sample scaffold might explain better

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 Column(
      children: [
        LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return AnimatedSwitcher(
            child: carouselSliderVisible
                ? Container(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    height: 200.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  )
                : Container(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    child: Text('dasdasdasd '),
                  ),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          );
        }),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                carouselSliderVisible = !carouselSliderVisible;
              });
            },
            child: Text('data'),
          ),
        )),
      

],
    )
```

that part of your code which you want animate, is not clear so I use simple example.

Comment: Good old AnimatedSwitcher, I forgot about it.

Comment: It's looking way better but I have two different heights of this widgets.
Any solution how to animate change of height?

Comment: the height is not the problem.

Comment: but change of height it's not animating, that's the problem

Comment: the important part is use different key.

Comment: ooo, I see.  could you please put your complete widget so I can edit my answer with your code?

Comment: My complete widget is huge. I edited my question, now in 2nd snippet is everything what  is needed.

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: did update worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it's working, I just only changed AnimatedSwitcher for AnimatedSize

Answer (score 1):

You can use in-built widgets to animate the changes:
e.g

- [AnimatedCrossFade](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html)
- [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) for most custom animation.

Be careful with keys, if you try to animate Widgets with the same type you need to set custom keys to the widgets.

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
   child: first? 
          Container(key:ValueKey('first'), color: Colors.red) : 
          Container(key:ValueKey('second'), color: Colors.blue)
)
```